# Filter a table with an array of criteria derived from another table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, filter

In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250717/filter-a-table-for-each-row-from-another-table) I figured out how to filter a table with for each row from another table. Now I need to filter again another table with an array of criteria from the filtered table.

When I use the code I tagged here underneath, I recieve an error; Type mismatch.

Ultimately I need to print every result of this loop.

Edit: This question is now solved. The code underneath is working brialliantly!

```
    Sub LoopDoorAfdelingV4()

Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myTable2 As ListObject
Dim c As Long
Dim myArray As Variant


Dim myGroupIDFilter As Variant
Dim myGroupNameFilter As Variant

Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TabelGroupID")
Set myGroupIDFilter = myTable.ListColumns(1).Range
Set myGroupNameFilter = myTable.ListColumns(2).Range
Set myTable2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TabelAfdelingenIntern")  

For c = 2 To myTable.ListRows.Count

ActiveSheet.Range(myTable2).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myGroupNameFilter(c)

Set myfilteredgroup = myTable2.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

With Application
    myArray = .Transpose(myfilteredgroup)
End With


Worksheets("Vorige werkdag").Range("$E$2:$P$10000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=myArray, _
Operator:=xlFilterValues

Worksheets("Vorige werkdag").PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
       IgnorePrintAreas:=False

Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd speculate that this is due to the way you've set the Array will generate a `2D` array and the `Criteria1:=myArray` is expecting a `1D` array.

If your data is in a column you can use

```
With Application
    myArray = .Transpose(myfilteredgroup.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
End With
```

and if it is a row use

```
With Application
    myArray = .Transpose(.Transpose(myfilteredgroup.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)))
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. It almost works. It is selecting all the cells, but it should only select the ones that are filtered (visible). Any suggestions to solve this?`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`?

Comment: @Joeyb I've updated my answer you need to use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to get the non-filtered ones. This can be moved to where you set the `myfilteredgroup` object

Comment: Thanks Tom! I did however had to change one more thing. The position of where I set `myArray` was wrong, for it to work it needed to be included in the loop itself and not outside :)